# i see an open udp connection on port 50113 on server

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.04, ufw

I just setup a new server and see an established connection on port 50113 (udp).  I do not recall setting up anything on the server that would require port 50113 (tcp or udp).  I have ufw/ip tables - and none of the ufw rules allow for traffic on port 50113 - however, even after ufw is enabled, I still see the connection.  Running sudo netstat -tulpn does not give the name of the process (perhaps I am making a mistake with the command).  Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this and figure out which process this might be (and if not one that I spawned., close the connection down)

Comment: denying outbound connections on ufw dropped the connection (or so I think)

Comment: Exactly what did you see?

Comment: udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50113         127.0.0.1:50113         ESTABLISHED

Comment: You can try `sudo lsof -i | grep :50113` to find out what is using the port

Comment: changing the ufw rule seemed to have fixed it.  I have had to add a number of rules in ufw to keep "friends" from united states, russia and china out of the server.  Such a joy and a great way to spend my saturday